# End script when Powershell input validation fails or generates exception

Tags: validation, powershell

I have the following code in my powershell script to validate user input (The first positional argument in the script):

```
function validatePath {
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({
        If ($_ -match "^([a-z]:\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d])*)") {
            $True
        } Else {
            Write-Host "Please enter a valid path,$_ is not a valid path."
            Write-debug $_.Exception
            Break
        }
    })]
    [string]$filePath
)
Process
{
    Write-Host "The path is "$filePath
}
}

validatePath -filePath $args[0]
```

My problem is, currently when the validation fails, and the code goes in the Else block and hits Break, instead of stopping the entire script from continue running, it goes to the next block and everything continues and more errors come out.

Question is, how can I modify my code so that When the validation fails to match the regex, it will throw an appropriate error message and stops the entire script from running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable inside the script to `Stop`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

function validatePath {
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({
        If ($_ -match "^([a-z]:\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d])*)") {
            $True
        } Else {
            Write-Host "Please enter a valid path,$_ is not a valid path."
            Write-debug $_.Exception
            Break
        }
    })]
    [string]$filePath
)
Process
{
    Write-Host "The path is "$filePath
}
}

validatePath -filePath $args[0] 
Do-MoreStuff # this won't execute if parameter validation fails in the previous call
```

See the [`about_Preference_Variables` help file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables) for more information

Answer (score -1):

use "exit" to stop the entire script. Put any message before the "exit".

Comment: Does not work, script is still going after I set exit inside the block.